# Efficient quantum algorithms to decompose Hessian matrices into sums of unitaries

Tags: circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation, pauli-gates

Are there efficient quantum algorithms that given a d-sparse hessian $H \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ decompose it into a sum of unitaries (e.g. Pauli matrices)?

$$H = \sum_i^q a_i U_i$$

If an algorithm exists, how could I contruct a quantum circuit for it?

Comment: are Hessian matrices arbitrary symmetric matrices, or do they have some further structure?

Comment: They are arbitary in general. Though for my case real symmetric sparse matrices also suffice. They are constructed from Finite Element problems, I don't think that helps though.

Comment: In the original VQLS paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05820.pdf, there is a section (Appendix A) that showed how you can express a sparse matrices as LCU efficiently.

Comment: @KAJ226 I have that in mind. There are some oracles there which are assumed to be known. Do I have to figure them out based on linear algebra?